# Can meteor be used to develop mobile app completely

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jquery-mobile, meteor

I am a novice in Meteor and have never worked with Android or IOS programming.

Currently I am using meteor to develop a mobile-device application.

So I am wondering, is it possible through meteor to develop a complete mobile application,I did some little research and saw that there are couple of packages to implement swipe or send notifications. But what if want to build a solid mobile application, like implementing alarm, snoozing it all? As told already I am novice in meteor and carry no knowledge of mobile development, so any suggestion for good tutorials is also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure, you can do that! Meteor supports building cross-platform mobile apps for iOS and Android from version 0.9.4.

To check it just do:

`meteor create --example todos`

`cd todos`

`meteor install-sdk android`

`meteor add-platform android`

`meteor run android`

Thant's it!
Actually you can build (almost?)any meteor with using cordova/phoneGap and run in on your Android/iOS device.

For more information you should read: https://www.meteor.com/try/7

Also I would recommend to watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4dJLPLWMImw

Comment: This is the basic answer and it's correct. What's more interesting is some flesh around it - what UI/CSS framework from Atmosphere works on mobile? How can one get mobile-specific interactions (swipe, notifications as the OP mentioned) or mobile-specific UI elements like off-canvas menus (not standard in Bootstrap)?